# Find shortest path in a directed graph that goes through some specified vertices

Tags: algorithm, optimization, graph-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm

There is a weighted directed graph.How to get the shortest path in the directed graph that goes through some specified vertices.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Algorithm Optimization - Shortest Route Between Multiple Points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1511585/algorithm-optimization-shortest-route-between-multiple-points)

Answer (score 0):

Actually this problem falls into the class of NP, because Hamiltonian path, the well-known NP problem, can be reduced to this problem. So you might use brute force search or some approximation algorithm.